# Looking for a neutral adjective to describe something covered by a gel-like substance?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to translate a text to English and am stuck at this sentence: "From the water and hair styling product his hand was [...]". Now try as I may, I can only think of words that have strong negative connotations to me, such as slimy, and none such is intended here. What would be a more fitting and neutral word?

Comment: *Sticky*......?

Comment: I may stick to that if I don't find an alternative. However, adhesive is not quite the intended meaning here (because of the water too).

Comment: I'm not sure how this styling product + water feels but my hands feel kind of "creamy" when they've got shampoo on them ... but maybe that's to far over the neutral line on the other extreme (and you'd probably need to add "yet" when describing the taste, 'cause something "creamy" should probably taste good, not strange: "and YET so tasted strange/tasted so strange."

Comment: Hahah, true. "creamy" wouldn't be too bad, but then again I am not writing porn here ;)

Comment: +1 @ermanen.  His hand was slick and sticky with the water and hair styling gel.

Comment: "slick and sticky" is actually so perfectly simple that I facepalmed when I read it. Never would have occurred to me to use two words. That's why I should leave translation to professional translators.

Comment: If you are really OK with "sticky", you may want to edit your question to remove the "neutral" requirement because "sticky" has negative connotations, though "slick" does not.

Comment: Maybe it does a bit, but not nearly as bad as slimy? That's as close to a compromise I can get at the moment, and slick kinda neutralizes it.

Comment: Actually you could probably leave 'sticky' out and just say "...his hand was slick with hair gel". I think that conveys the right meaning and the stickiness is implied anyway... Good call @TimRomano

Comment: Yes, I think I will do just that. If @Tim Romano makes this into an answer, I will mark it accepted.

Comment: Sticky is negative; just use slick.

Comment: "viscid" or "viscous" (having relatively high resistance to flow). Also "mucilaginous".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ['slippery'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slippery?s=t)

> Slippery - **adjective**
>
> 1 - tending or liable to cause slipping or sliding, as ice, oil, a wet surface, etc.: a slippery road.
>
> 2 - tending to slip from the hold or grasp or from position: a slippery rope.
>
> www.dictionary.com

Or perhaps ['gelatinous'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gelatinous?s=t)

> Gelatinous - **adjective**
>
> 1 - having the nature of or resembling jelly, especially in consistency; jellylike.
>
> 2 - pertaining to, containing, or consisting of gelatin.
>
> www.dictionary.com

Or there is also ['gelatinated'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gelatinize) or ['gelatinized'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gelatinize)

> Gelatinize - **verb** (used with object), gelatinized, gelatinizing.
>
> 1 - to make gelatinous.
>
> 2 - **to coat with gelatin**, as paper. [my emphasis]
>
> www.dictionary.com

Comment: Thank you. I thought about "slippery", it is in fact the most often used translation of the word in the original text, yet it doesn't seem all that relevant in context.

Answer (score -1):

"covered in a gel-like substance"?

Comment: Hahah, not quite useful here. Full disclosure: the text is a tour report, and I am trying to describe the interaction of someone in the front row with the vocalist. The context is: "I licked his palm. From the water and hair styling product it was (...), and so tasted strange." Fangirls will be weird, but I promised to translate this, so... :)